# Python. Скачать таблицу из Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Сделал программу, которая скачивает из почты прайсы и работает с ними. Но есть еще один прайс, который находится на третьей странице таблицы, к которой мне расшарили доступ в Google Sheets. Как бы его скачать?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python